# アニメーション付きのメッシュをBlenderにインポートするとメッシュが暴れる

Tags: blender

### 前提

BlenderのVer:2.83

### 問題

Blenderで自作したメッシュをMixamoへアップロードし、リギングとアニメーションの付与をした後に、
再度BlenderへImportして、アニメーションを再生すると以下の画像のように、メッシュが暴れてしまいます。
暴れる、というよりは様々な方向へ回転してしまいます。

※本来ション時の画像を一部抜粋

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

メッシュが上に行ったり、下に行ったり、左上をむいてしまったり...

インポート時の設定は以下の通りです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Blenderに読み込もうとしているファイル形式はFBXです。
Mixamoへアップロードする前はメッシュのみのOBJファイルを出力し、Mixamoへアップロードしています。

解決策が分かる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。